# Custom IE script tag syntax with Slim (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, assets, slim-lang

I want to create a script tag for IE only, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="..."></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The js file is in assets/javascript, so it will be precompiled and i have to point to the digest file via asset_path.
How could I write it in Slim?